# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found : Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, but I get the: **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found** when I reference my **/tasks/create** **route**. Can someone help me ?

This is my route in **routes/web.php**:

```
Route::get('/tasks/create', 'TasksController@create');
```

My **TasksController** in **App/Http/Controllers**:

```
public function create()

   {
        // GET / tasks/create
        return view('tasks.create');
    }
```

and finally my view **create.blade.php** in **resources/views/tasks**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Task</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Add a new task</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and see if the route you're accessing is registered.

Comment: yep, it is registered.

Comment: compose dump-autoload or composer update or try removing cache files from bootstrap/cache folder

Comment: I would like to mention that all my other routes are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think root for laravel folder is not the root of your laravel folder. Please try the following. I hope it'll help you

```
DocumentRoot "<your-laravel-path>/public"
```